# YourKit allocation tracing

Tags: java, profiling, yourkit

I'm profiling an application with a YourKit profiler, and there's something which baffles me.

Allocation tracing is on, with stack recording, for each 100th object. At the %application%->memory->allocations view there are, say, 20k objects recorded.

Now I take a memory snapshot and go to the allocations->call tree view. Most of the objects are listed as `<Objects without allocation information>`, and I see about 100 recorded allocations.

Why the descrepancy? Do I miss something in these figures' meaning?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons:

1) You start allocation recording not from JVM startup

2) You are recording not all objects, but each N-th

Both situations are controlled by alloceach= YourKit agent startup option. Details are here http://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/startup_options.jsp

Vladimir Kondratyev
YourKit, LLC